# Is there a reference for using Direct3D with COM?

Tags: c++, windows, com, direct3d

What I'm referring to is how all the MSDN tutorials for "unmanaged"/desktop C++ target applications make no use of or even mention COM beyond the fact that Direct3D is a COM interface. I'm *new* to this game and through a lot of searching (including reading other MSDN docs for other targets -- like RT) I've determined that I definitely should be using the COM helpers.

I've found references for the COM smart pointer (_com_ptr_t its companion _COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF), but nothing more than that.

How much more do I need to know about COM to work with it?
The requirements for the Direct3D tutorials on MSDN simply state that C++ experience and maths.

I don't think I'm confused on which smart pointer to use any more (as this is another common question), but I am concerned that as a new COM programmer there might be other VITAL information I'm missing.

Also, apparently other COM interfaces define their own pointer typedefs for programmers. Does this exist for Direct3D as well? Right now I'm just using _COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF and defining my own.

Comment: `I've determined that I definitely should be using the COM helpers.` Why? After what I've seen, it's not very intuitive and rather outdated. I see no reason why you should need to use it for Direct3D development.

Comment: Calling it COM is a big stretch.  It is IUnknown based, that's all.  You are not missing anything, _com_ptr_t is fine, so is CComPtr or WRL's ComPtr.

Comment: @olevegard That is the self determination of someone who's brand new to the Direct3D (et. al.) world. I probably stretched a bit and meant to say that as a c++ programmer, I want to be using smart pointers and not the example used in the MSDN tutorials (which all seem to be bare pointers).

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. I read a subtle comment in another author's article regarding _com_ptr_t, it was the extent of the COM knowledge requirement for Direct3D. All of this is obviously from unofficial sources.

Comment: If smart pointers are the only reason for you to use it, I reccomend that you take a look at C++11. It requires a newish version of Visual Studio, but they're very easy to use, and you don't have to use COM

Comment: I do appreciate the advice, and I've seen others recommend or attempt that path. It usually ends with the recommendations to just use the COM helpers provided. I'm just starting out and there's already been plenty of differing opinions. (Some of them even internal) :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I'd recommend using `ComPtr` in `wrl.h` for your smart COM pointers.  For D3D, you don't really need to know much COM aside from how it manages object lifetimes via `AddRef` and `Release`, and knowing when to use the occasional `QueryInterface` (e.g. to get `ID3D11Debug` from `ID3D11Device`).  The only thing specific to D3D11 is that the lifetime of a D3D object is the greater of its actual COM lifetime (i.e. period where the reference count is greater than zero), and the period where it or its dependencies exist or are bound to the D3D pipeline.

For example:

```
CreateTexture(&tex) // tex refcount = 1
CreateShaderResourceView(tex, &srv) // srv refcount = 1, tex internal refcount = 2
tex->Release() // tex refcount = 0, internal refcount = 1 (so not released)
srv->Release() // srv refcount = 0, released; tex internal refcount = 0, released
```

Naturally, smart pointers automatically call `AddRef` and `Release` as object references are copied or go out of scope. They're definitely a good idea if you're new to the API and don't want to worry about forgetting to release something (D3D's internal reference tracking ensures you can't delete something that's currently in use).  For more advanced programs though, you'll want to locate object allocation and release more precisely (rather than just scope changes), so will need to manage it manually.

Comment: Is there an additional dependency for using wrl.h (being WinRT)? Why is that better than using _com_ptr_t?

Comment: @jacobsd Shouldn't be any dependencies - it's just templates in headers. WRL is compatible with WinRT but doesn't require it.  It's perfectly valid to use it in a Win32 desktop app.

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. Is there a good reason to using it over _com_ptr_t?